# How to setup graphQL inside a craft cms 4 project

Tags: graphql, craftcms

For an assignment, I have to make a map that can show data. That data is stored inside some entries. I have to fetch that data with graphQL. I've managed to build the query with the GraphQL IDE, but I have no clue how to set everything up in my actual project. Do I have to make a seperated folder or not, where do I have to store the queries, what about routing..

The documentation isn't helping me a lot so I hope one of you can't help me out..